# Angular5 Ngx-chart : donut chart - Labels inside and outside

Tags: angular, pie-chart, donut-chart, ngx-charts

1.How we can add title to chart below the chart.
2.How we can add a lable inside the donut circle in Angular ngx-chart.

Thanks in advance.